# SonarQube multi-language module within multi-modules project

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I have a multi mudule project with lots of modules and most of them are java. therefore i set in the root pom the sonar.language to java.
however, one of my module contains both java and js so in order to disable the sonar.language property i had to add the following to this module pom:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>execute</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <source>
                    project.properties.remove('sonar.language')
                </source>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

is there a cleaner way to have a default language and unset it in one of the modules?

Comment: Why do you not simply drop sonar.language=java from root module ?

Comment: The answer is simple - most of the projects that store dozens of modules contains java code.

Comment: That's the principle. It won't change anything for these Java projects. Multi-language feature does not mean that there should be more than one language analyzed. If all the installed plugins correctly support SonarQube 4.2+, then the property "sonar.language" should be dropped.